# VBA update subform recordsource

Tags: ms-access, vba

Quick and easy one (Probably) for you.

My home form has a lot of sub forms within tab controls. Some of these sub-forms have their own sub-form based off a query and that query has criteria input control on the parent form.

As you can imagine upon loading the home form I would have to enter all the parameters in pop-up boxes as the subforms/queries are also loading.

My work-around for this is setting those query sub-forms recordsource to ""
Then once the user control that applies the where condition is updated it changes their record source to the query.

Only, my code (Below) doesn't work. And After half hour of staring at it I can't figure out why, it produces no errors it just does nothing.

All fields/records just have #NAME?

```
Private Sub txt_EventID_AfterUpdate()
Me.txt_forcefocus.SetFocus
Me.sub_SpeakerOnboarding.Form.RecordSource = qry_SpkrOnboard
Me.Requery
End Sub
```

I also tried the following:

```
Private Sub txt_EventID_AfterUpdate()
Me.txt_forcefocus.SetFocus
Me.sub_SpeakerOnboarding.Form.RecordSource = qry_SpkrOnboard
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Again no results, nothing... All fields/records just have #NAME?

Hopefully I've missed something simple otherwise I'll have to rethink the entire form designs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*RecordSource* is a string:

```
Private Sub txt_EventID_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txt_forcefocus.SetFocus
    Me.sub_SpeakerOnboarding.Form.RecordSource = "qry_SpkrOnboard"
End Sub
```

To refer to a control on the subform:

```
Value = Me![SubformControlNAME].Form![txt_EventID].Value
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav... I should have known that.

Related question now the recordsource updates. In the query, to reference the form control I would usually use [Forms]![usf_OnboardingOverview]![txt_EventID] however as [Forms]![usf_OnboardingOverview]![txt_EventID] is technically a subform of [usf_Home] this keeps returning asking for parameters and it doesn't seem to like [Forms]![usf_Home]![usf_OnboardOverview.Form]![txt_EventID]

Comment: You need the `Form` property. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Thanks again. I gave it a go and it keeps asking for the parameter. My head is too fried now with other more critical issues with my DB so I'll use a tempvars method for now and revisit subform referencing next week maybe.

Comment: OK. _Missing parameter_ typically means a misspelled or missing field name.